# How to select all elements in DOM with exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a function on all elements in DOM except for an element with a specified class and I have also tried these and they don't work for some reason:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*:not(.exception)').someFunction();
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').not(".exception").someFunction();
});
```

I have also tried `$("body")` instead of all-selector `$("*")`

Comment: And you're sure it's not working exactly as intended, but the `*` selector is also getting you elements like `body`, etc. and for instance certain styles would apply to children elements

Comment: @adeneo I'm actually trying to load a number converter on the whole DOM but I want numbers in some elements not to be converted

Comment: And you're sure this converter doesn't also work on children elements of whatever element you run it on. The `*` selector is horrible, it selects everything, even the head and body elements, meaning your plugin has to actively make sure it doesn't affect nested elements

Comment: @adeneo no the function should not run on the element itself all its children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `:not()` and `.not()` both are working. But if you put a selector on all the elements for a function like `click()`, when you click on the excluded object, the function for that object is not called, but it is called for all the parent elements it has.

For example, if you select all for `.click()` and click a button in the body, the function will be called for `html`, `body` and `button`. Thus if you put alert, even after clicking the button once, you will have 3 alerts.

In the case where you want the function to be executed only once, selecting all does not work.
But when want a function to be executed for all elements, it will work.

In the following code I have added both the examples. Suppose you want a `.click()` on all elements except `btn2`. So you select all and exlude it. By clicking `btn1`, one alert should pop up while for `btn2` no alert should be there. But clicking `btn1` will cause 3 alert boxes while clicking the excluded `btn2` will cause 2 alert boxes. You can see the order in which the function is executed through the console.

At the same time, for the function `css()` it works perfectly.

Hope it helps!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').not(".exception").click(someFunction);
    function someFunction(){
        alert("alert");
        console.log(this);
    }
    $('*').not(".exception").css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<button>btn1</button>
<button class="exception">btn2</button>
```

So after `someFunction()` is executed on every element in DOM you need to execute another function on elements with `.exception` class to revert what `someFunction()` has done.

Comment: yes you're right, so I guess I have to write another function to revert what `someFucntion()` did on the element and its children with `.exception` class

Comment: You can do that. But I think that there would be a better way to get the selection you want. I dont know the requirement you have so I cant say which will be better.

Comment: My whole site is in Persian and I need all numbers in the DOM to be converted to Farsi numbers except for some elements like those that contain email or English texts

Comment: Oh okay. Then yes maybe you will have to revert. Can't think of any other option.

Comment: I have used a non standard version of my font in which all English numbers are displayed in Farsi and for English content I will use some websafe fonts like sans-serif and apply it with a class (and I have given up using jquery)